# Product of densities of a wrapped normal distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, geometric-probability, special-functions

The density of a wrapped normal distribution is given by
$$\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi} }\sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty }\text{Exp}\left[\frac{-(\theta -\mu -2\pi k)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]$$
Considering two density functions $f(x),\ g(x)$ of a wrapped normal distribution with respective parameters $\mu_1,\ \mu_2$ and $\sigma_1,\ \sigma_2$, is the product $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ a density function of a wrapped normal distribution?

Comment: The total mass usually isn't $1$. 

Comment: Yes, it isn't. For the classical case of a normal distribution, it is possible to derive a formula for the new mass. I wonder whether there is a similar formula for the Wrapped Normal case.

Comment: one way to check is by seeing if the product of two Jacobi Theta functions is again some kind of Jacobi theta function with "reasonable" parameters---might be good to tag this question with "special-functions" to attract the attention of special function experts.

Comment: If $\mu_1 = 0$ and $\mu_2 = \pi$ and $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$ then for generic values of $\sigma_1$ the product is bimodal, which I think can't happen for a wrapped normal density.

Comment: Douglas' comment answers my question. Bimodality indeed can not happen in a wrapped normal distribution. Thus, the product of two wrapped normal densities is unfortunately not wrapped normal.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a follow-up on Suvrit's comment. There are plenty of formulas for products of theta functions, many of them found in [this Iowa State report.](http://orion.math.iastate.edu/jdhsmith/math/ProdIThF.pdf) (see particularly page 7). Whether any of them answer the OP's question is for the OP to find out (and tell us...)